# Xcode Copy Bundle Resources can't find files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, resourcebundle

Xcode can't find my Storyboards and my Info.plist in my **Copy Bundle Resources**, So my App doesn't run. I tried to add the Existing files again but they always appear red highlighted. I'm pretty sure it must be a local problem because when i clone the latest update from my repository on my other mac its runs without any problems. I already tried to re-install Xcode, delete files from **Xcode/DerivedData** and i also deleted the **com.apple.Xcode.plist**.
Anyone any ideas?

Comment: check info.plist is avail in your project or not and if is not there just add it , check the version of Xcode for both of u r mac systems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to reset your Simulator and then clean your App Build Folder

Comment: That actually worked....i tried it severals times before but somehow it worked now -,-

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the proposed solution works, but cleaning and re-compiling the entire app whenever a resource has changed is very tedious, especially for larger projects.

Therefore I came up with this solution that forces fresh resources in the app on a **per-directory** basis, without having to clean or recompile:

1. Add a 'Run Script Build Phase' (Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Run Script Build Phase)

   1. Copy/paste the following script into the build phase (don't forget to set the actual paths on line 1):

---

```
dirsToCopy=("path1/directory1","path2/directory2")

for INPATTERN in "${dirsToCopy[@]}"; do
    INDIR=$PROJECT_DIR/$INPATTERN/*
    OUTDIR=$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/$INPATTERN
    cp -R $INDIR $OUTDIR
done
```

---

For those not used to working with shell scripts:

- paths on line 1 of the script are relative to the project directory (where the .xcodeproj file resides)
- you can add more (or less) paths to the array `dirsToCopy` if you want
- you can change the pattern of files to copy where variable `INDIR` is defined
- you can change how the copying is done (currently, recursive due to `-R`) by changing the flags to `cp` in the last line of script within the for block.